# "Unexpected labeled statement" warnings with Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, arrow-functions, create-react-app

How would I go about fixing this block of Firebase-related code, to conform to CRA's ESLint rules:

```js
db.broadcasts.on('child_added', (snap) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        broadcasts: prevState.broadcasts.push(snap)
    });
});
```

Here are the related errors:[image]

I've tried [allowing loops](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-labels):

```
/*eslint no-labels: ["error", { "allowLoop": true }]*/
```

But that gave me the following error:

```
error    Unexpected labeled statement
```

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This rule found a bug in your code.
Rather than work around the rule, you need to fix the bug.

This part is parsed as a labeled statement:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    broadcasts: prevState.broadcasts.push(snap)
});
```

So the browser sees this:

```
this.setState(function(prevState) {
    broadcasts: // A label, like in switch() statement
      prevState.broadcasts.push(snap);
    // This function doesn't return anything
});
```

There are two issues here:

1) **Do not mutate `prevState`.** This is not how React state works. You need to **return** the next state rather than mutate it in place.

2) You are not using the ES6 arrow function correctly. **If you want to implicitly return object, you must put it in parens.** Otherwise the browser parses it as a labeled statement. This is why you get a confusing message about labels.

So, the correct version would look like this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ // Note this paren! It is essential.
    broadcasts: prevState.broadcasts.concat([snap]) // Note lack of mutation!
}));
```

Learn more about [why immutability is important](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#why-immutability-is-important) and about [returning object literals from arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals).