# I got the "Unexpected labeled statement " beacuse of "outer_loop" and I didnt convert code to modern javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have a code as below and I get an error in pipeline when pushing the code to git. I am getting the "Unexpected labeled statement" error in the "outer_loop". How can I correct this error.

```
             outer_loop:
             while ((c = nextPixel()) != EOF) {
              fcode = (c << BITS) + ent;
              i = (c << hshift) ^ ent;
              if (htab[i] === fcode) {
                ent = codetab[i];
                continue;
              } else if (htab[i] >= 0) {
                disp = hsize_reg - i;
                if (i === 0) disp = 1;
                do {
                  if ((i -= disp) < 0) i += hsize_reg;
                  if (htab[i] === fcode) {
                    ent = codetab[i];
                    continue outer_loop;
                  }
                } while (htab[i] >= 0);

              }
              output(ent, outs);
              ent = c;
              if (free_ent < 1 << BITS) {
                codetab[i] = free_ent++;
                htab[i] = fcode;
              } else {
                cl_block(outs);
              }
            }
```

Comment: Please add more surrounding context to the code.

Comment: That's all my code. I'm getting an "Unexpected labeled statement" error because of "outer_loop". What else should I add @Barmar

Comment: Where is that coming from? Are you running `jslint` or `eslint` in your github actions?

Comment: Shot in the dark, since you mentioned "error in pipeline when pushing to git": Your project's ESLint is configured to disallow label statements. This is not uncommon and a preset in project starters like Create React App.

Comment: That error usually happens when you have an object literal in a context where `{` signifies a code block, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788811/unexpected-labeled-statement-react-native or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993719/unexpected-labeled-statement-warnings-with-create-react-app

Comment: I want to without "outer_loop" loop. do you have any your suggestion? @Barmar

Comment: If you don't want to use a statement label, put the outer loop in a function and use `return` to break out of it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/184513/1491895